# app crash after opening push notification

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com in sending push notifications 
My app is working correctly and push notifications sent successfuly to device , but when I open the notification app getting forced close .
my logcat error is :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity java.lang.NullPointerException
```

where my OnResume() on main class is:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (this.getIntent() != null) {
        final Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            final String tabTag = extras.getString("tab_tag");

            if (tabTag.equals("All Photos"))
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            else if (tabTag.equals("Favorite"))
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            else
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Either tabTag or mViewPager has to be null from the code you've shown. I would guess that it's tabTag, but it's also possible that mViewPager got destroyed somehow and is null during onResume. Try checking if either is null using an if statement and then print out which is is in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say with the limited stacktrace given, as we do not know the exact line where the code breaks. So I'm assuming the exception is thrown somewhere in the OnResume() method you provided.

If the `NullPointerException` is thrown on this line:

```
if (tabTag.equals("All Photos"))
```

then variable `tabTag` is null, indicating either a) the value of "tab_tag" is null, or b) the key `"tab_tag"` doesn't exist in the `extras` bundle you're reading from.

However, if the `NullPointerException` is thrown on this line:

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

then `mViewPager` is null, indicating either a) `mViewPager` hasn't been initialized, or b) the instance of `mViewPager` that was initialized, has been lost.